# Retrieving all layers of WMS?

Tags: wms, ogc

I'd like to display data of a WMS (WebMapService) that contains different layers. The URL of the capabilities document is:

http://geoportal.saarland.de/mapbender/php/wms.php?**layer_id=41183**&PHPSESSID=152fa295e90a06833f823fd2a3fcff34&REQUEST=GetCapabilities&VERSION=1.1.1&SERVICE=WMS&withChilds=1

The problem is about the layer_id. To retrieve the WMS data, the Parameter "layer_id" is needed. But I want to see several layers (about 170 layers) of the WMS, so I don't want to send several requests with varying URLs.

**Is there any possibility to obtain all layers at once?**

I already tried setting the Parameter to "layer_id=all" or "layer_id=*".

Comment: May I ask, why would you like to display 170 layers on a map in the first place? Isn’t that too much clutter on the map? Or does each layer represent another area?

Comment: Right, each layer contains a land-use plan of one municipality within one Geman federal state (called Saarland). I want to get an overview over the whole federale state, that's why I need to display them all together in one map.

Comment: Potentially using a VRT file